# What is the best way to develop dynamic jQuery Mobile mobile app?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile, dynamic, cordova

I need to develop mobile app with jQuery Mobile which will be packed with PhoneGap Build and distributed on Google Play. I need to have dynamic listviews which depending on which item is clicked will open new dynamically generated page which got information from MySql database.

Current setup is I generate listview with urls with different variables attached (`category.html?cat=1`, `category.html?cat=2`, ...) when I click on item the `pageinit` event is triggered for `category.html` and I parse (with JS) the url variable (`cat=2`) and I send query to my PHP page (which in turn query MySql) through `$.get` method and I insert the returned value (which is listview echoed back by PHP page) with `$('div.ui-content').append(data).trigger('create')`. This way sometimes works, sometimes doesn't(the page stays blank) or you must refresh the whole page etc. ...

Is it better to generate whole html for page in PHP and dynamically transition to new page with `changePage()` method? Or is any other method better?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use 3 components,

server side framework:  Slim is the easiest for this, nice simple routing, easy to implement, you can also do symphony, rails, etc

middleman: handlebars is great for inserting incoming data into html, try it for sure.  angular is good as well, more complicated though.  also with handlebars, you can have a different template file for every different page, very easy to maintain.

front end: jquery mobile is the most compprehensive i believe, ajax requests are piece of cake, and in the requests you can call your handlebars templates and insert stuff on the fly.

PS:  you are still doing all this with "one" html page, but handlebars is helping you insert sub pages on the fly, jquery mobile helps you change the pages